# The knapsack problem, visual studio issues

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dynamic

I implemented a dynamic programming solution to the famous knapsack problem. Now the funny part of this is that visual studio will not allow my code to compile yet when I copy and paste my code in cpp.sh it runs fine with no errors.

At the moment this is what I am getting in visuial studio for errors:

```
    Unhandled exception at 0x0FADED76 (ucrtbased.dll) in Practice.exe: An invalid 
parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.
```

This occurs at line 10, i.e. `dp[i][j] = 0`. I am not sure how to fix this issue, and in general I have noticed that visual studio can be particularly  whiny.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int maxKnapSack(std::vector<int>& v, std::vector<int>& w, int capacity) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> dp(capacity + 1, std::vector<int>(v.size() + 1));
    for (int i = 0; i <= v.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= capacity; j++) {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0) {
                dp[i][j] = 0;
            }
            else if (j - w[i - 1] >= 0) {
                dp[i][j] = std::max(v[i-1] + dp[i - 1][j - w[i-1]], dp[i - 1][j]);
            }
            else {
                dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return dp[v.size()][capacity];
}


int main() {

    std::vector<int> v = { 10, 4, 7 };
    std::vector<int> w = { 4, 2, 3 };
    int capacity = 5;

    std::cout << "The maximum I can get is " << maxKnapSack(v, w, capacity) << "\n";

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: you are going out of range. the range is 0..size()-1. you are going 0..size().

Answer (score 3):

Your vector `dp` contains `6` elements, each element being a vector of `4` elements. It's equivalent to the array definition `int dp[6][4]`.

Your outer loop loop from `0` to `4` (inclusive) and the inner loop loops from `0` to `6` (inclusive). That means you will use index out of bounds in the nested (inner) vector.

Your loops should be the other way around with their limits. Or your vector `dp` should be defined with the sizes switched.

---

Your conditions inside the inner loop are also wrong. The condition `i == 0 || j == 0` will be *false* if e.g. `i == 0` *and* `j != 0`. That will then lead to you using negative indexes because of `i - 1`. That is also out of bounds and again lead to *undefined behavior*.

You need to make sure that the `else if` only happens when `i > 0` and `j - w[i-1] > 0` as well. And the `else` only when `i > 0`.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow, the code runs perfectly on http://cpp.sh/, can you be more specific?

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx The vector (of vectors) `dp` can be used with `dp[0][0]` to `dp[5][3]`. Your loops go to `dp[3][5]`. That means you go out of bounds of the inner vector, and that leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). And undefined behavior sometimes have the property of seemingly working, unfortunately.

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx Switch your loops? Switch you vector dimensions? Either way will work (but not both at the same time!)

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx Yes, and the inner loop to `v.size()`.

Comment: That still does not fix the problem, the error now points to the first else if block.

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx You need to rethink your conditions, you will use `i - 1` when `i == 0`.